# Infinite Geometric Series distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \text{Geometric}(p)$

Show that $P(X>k)=(1-p)^k$ for any integer $k$. Hint: $\sum_{x=1}^{k}r^{x}=\frac{r-r^{k+1}}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$

I'm completely lost with this, I can't see how the hint relates to the question.

Answer (score 3):

$$P(X > k) = 1 - P(X \leq k) =1 - \sum_{j=1}^k p\left(1-p\right)^{j-1} = 1 - \frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{j=1}^k (1-p)^{j}$$
Now use your hint....

Answer (score 0):

An odd way of doing it! The number of trials before the first success is $\gt k$ precisely if there are $k$ failures in a row. The probability of this is $(1-p)^k$.

If we *really* want to compute using a geometric series, the probability that $X\gt k$ is
$$\sum_{k+1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{i-1}.$$
This is an infinite geometric series, first term $p(1-p)^k$, common ratio $1-p$, so the sum is $p(1-p)^k \frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$, which is $p^k$.